# Object Mapper giving different response in similar implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper

I have two different Java projects. In both the project, we wanted keys of response object to be configurable based on request header. So, we created a [JsonUtils class](https://gist.github.com/amitgaurav11/8676c33b0d1cead8924eeb00e9a95b65) that can be used in the both projects using below method.

```
public String getResponseJson(String casing, Object response) {
        if (casing.equals(SNAKE_CASE)) {
            return JsonUtils.toJson(response);
        } else {
            return JsonUtils.toCamelCaseJson(response);
        }
    }
```

In 1st project we want request Json keys to be in snake case, So added this config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

After adding this config in 1st project, [JsonUtils class](https://gist.github.com/amitgaurav11/8676c33b0d1cead8924eeb00e9a95b65)
`getResponseJson` method started giving this kind of API response.

```
"[{\"columnName\":\"transporterName\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"consignorName\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"consigneeName\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"locationName\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"locationCode\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"locationCity\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"packageKey1\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"packageKey2\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"packageKey3\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"vehicleType\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"tripKey1\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"tripKey2\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"tripKey3\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"state\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"pincode\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"country\",\"dataType\":\"String\"},{\"columnName\":\"material\",\"dataType\":\"String\"}]"
```

```
But, my requirement is proper Json response.
```

Note: We are also using hibernate dependency in our first project. I guess hiberante's objectMapper is being used and creating issue. We can't remove hibernate from the project as it is required.

But in 2nd project we wanted request Json keys to be in camel case.So we did not add this config in second project. And it is working fine as it is giving proper json response (not as stringified json)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to change the stringified response into proper Json Response.